# clear and disable textbox when checkbox checked

Tags: jquery

I can disable the textbox when the checkbox is selected, but I can't figure out how to clear the textbox if anything is in it.

```
  <input type="text" id="form_sc1"/>
  <input type="checkbox" id="form_setchange"/>
```

JQuery

```
                $(document).ready(function(){
                 if($('input.form_setchange').is(':checked')){
                       $("#form_sc1").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                 }
```

Comment: `$("#form_sc1").val("")` and correct your selector instead of `$('input.form_setchange').is(...` it should be `$('input#form_setchange').is(...`

Comment: doesn't work, i have added it to the existing function, and an entirely separate one.

Comment: why "Kartikeya" solution not working ! it should work

Comment: sometimes attr will not work try prop instead 
`$("#form_sc1").prop("value", "");`

Comment: If i just set the value = '  ', it disables the textbox. Still won't remove the text.

Comment: see demo here https://jsfiddle.net/65gp2uzo/

Comment: @user2168066 checkout my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input:checkbox').on('click', function(){
      if($('input:checkbox').is(':checked')){
        $('input:text').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('input:text').val('');
      }
      else{
        $('input:text').prop('disabled', false);
      }
  });
});
```

Working JSFiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/86Lv2urz/1/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('input:checkbox').on('click', function(){
    $('input:text').prop('disbaled', 'disabled');
    $('input:text').val('');
});
```

Comment: Same thing, disables but does not remove the text.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this-

```
$('#form_setchange').attr("value", "");
```

OR

```
$('#form_setchange').val('');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('input.form_setchange').is(':checked')){
     $("#form_sc1").prop("disabled", true).val('');
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. You should try to explain your answer a little more thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below code once

```
 $('#form_setchange').change(function() {
   var $check = $(this);
   if ($check.prop('checked')) {
     $("#form_sc1").val('');
     $("#form_sc1").attr("disabled", "disabled"); 
   } else {
     $("#form_sc1").removeAttr("disabled"); 
   }
});
```

Hope it may helps...